Minimum Cell Changes to Ensure Unique Numbers in Each Row and Column of an $ n \times n $ Table
We have an $ n \times n $ table, and in each cell of the table, there is a number from $1$ to $ 2n $. We want to change the numbers in some of the cells and replace them with other numbers from $1$ to $ 2n $ such that in the end, all the numbers in each row and each column are distinct. What is the minimum number of cells we need to change?
I'm actually looking for an algorithm (so I'm able to program it) for this problem. I also asked it on programming stack exchange websites, but they told me I should ask it here. So any helps would be appreciated.
I have tried using dynamic programming and assumed the subproblems are $i\times i$ minors of the grid. However, I couldn't make significant progress with this approach. I also attempted to reduce the problem to graph problems, such as matchings, but again, I didn't succeed in finding a solution.
Any hints or help would be immensely valuable to me.

Where does this problem come from btw?

Let's call a set $A$ of cells good, if  all the numbers in each row and each column in $A$ are distinct.
Firstly, note that if we choose some good set $A$, then we can replace numbers from other cells in a way, so the entire table becomes good. Let's replace numbers from cells not in $A$ one by one. Every time there will be no more than $2n-2$ numbers, that we can not place in the current cell. So, there will always be a number that can be put in this cell.
Thus, our goal is to find the largest good set $A$. For every number $i$ consider the set $A_i$ made up of all cells from $A$, which contain the number $i$. Note that $A_i$ is a maximum good set of cells, each of them contaning the number $i$. So, our goal is to find set $A_i$ for every $i$.
This problem boils down to the Maximum Bipartite Matching problem. Consider the following bipartite graph $G$. The first set of vertices corresponds to $n$ rows of the table and the second set of vertices corresponds to $n$ columns of the table. Two vertices are connected by an edge iff at the intersection of their corresponding column and row there is a number $i$. Then the set $A_i$ correspond to the maximum mathcing. The maximum mathcing may be found, for example, via Kuhn's algorithm.
